# Evalute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{ n^2+n})$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I like to  find the following limit:

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin^2(\pi\sqrt{ n^2+n})$.

Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{n^2+n} \approx \sqrt{n^2}=n$. If this were equality then you would have $\sin(\pi n)=0$. Play with the error in this approximation.

Comment: @Ian In fact a much better approximation is $\;\sqrt{n^2+n}\cong n+\frac12\;$ , and because of this the limit in fact is like $$\;\sin^2\left(\pi\left(n+\frac12\right)\right)=1\;$$

Comment: @Joanpemo As it turns out, yes, but you can draw that conclusion by playing with the error in the leading order approximation (the $1/2$ being the first correction term).

Comment: @Ian Thank you. Yes, that's true.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sin^{2} \left(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + n}\right)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1586034/201168). See also [this same closed question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/877651/201168).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $n$ tends to $+\infty$, you may write
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^2 \left( \pi \sqrt{n^2+n}\right) &=\sin^2 \left( \pi n \:\sqrt{1+\frac1n}\right)\\\\
&=\sin^2 \left( \pi n \:\left(1+\frac1{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sin^2 \left( \pi n +\frac{\pi}2+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\cos^2 \left(\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\to 1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Dear Olivier Oloa, thank you very much, it was very nice and clear.

Comment: @user62498 You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Note that 
$$\sqrt{n^2+n}=\sqrt{n^2+n}-n+n=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}+n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/n}+1}+n.$$